# Capistrano 2 -> 3 git deployment differences?

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano, capistrano3

In my previous `capistrano` version 2 deployment of an app, I always got access to `git` on the deployed side with `.git` present.  This was handy when in a pinch we need to make a couple of tweaks server side and push them back to version control.

Now that we're moving to `capistrano` version 3 we've been missing the `.git` folder and obviously no longer can issue `git status`, etc. on this deployment.

**Is there an option I'm missing that has changed the functionality of cap 3 that removes `git` vs from a project upon deployment?**

It does indeed USE `git` for each deployment, but it's obviously doing something after the deploy to remove `.git`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the .git directory in #{repo_path} variable.